# Is there anyway to use Input::all() to create a new record?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.x. Is it possible to pass `Input:all()` rather than setting individual properties of object and then calling `save()`?

My form fields are similar to db fields in naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From laravel documentation you have options like -

```
$user = User::create(array('name' => 'John'));

// Retrieve the user by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$user = User::firstOrCreate(array('name' => 'John'));

// Retrieve the user by the attributes, or instantiate a new instance...
$user = User::firstOrNew(array('name' => 'John'));
```

You can use all these as following

```
$user = User::create(Input::all());

// Retrieve the user by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$user = User::firstOrCreate(Input::all());

// Retrieve the user by the attributes, or instantiate a new instance...
$user = User::firstOrNew(Input::all());
```

But you need to be careful that your form field name and database column names are same.

Also you have to look for $guarded on your model. Those field will not able to be inserted this way.

Comment: Thankyou! Is there anyway to lowercase input values of `Input:all()` without going thru loop?

Comment: Welcome. You can try this answer. Hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11008468/2120162

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Model::create(Input::all())`

For this to work, you need to specify a protected `$fillable` array in the model, which specifies mass-assignable fields.

```
protected $fillable=array('column1','cloumn2');
```